# How do I take the latest item given an ID in a list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Say I have objects that look like this

```
data class Test(val id: Int, val timeStamp: Long)
```

So a data set might look like

```
val data = listOf(

    Test(1, 100),
    Test(1, 150),
    Test(2, 50),
    Test(2, 150),
    Test(2, 300),
)
```

I want to be able to filter the list so that I get the latest timestamp of each ID, so my expected output is

```
data = listOf(
    Test(1, 150),
    Test(2, 300),
)
```

Was looking at using groupBy, but was not quite sure where to go from there. The list given is sorted ascending.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `groupBy` and `maxBy` like this:

```
data.groupBy { it.id }.values.map { it.maxBy(Test::timeStamp) }
```

In case of your data is sorted, you can use `last` instead of `maxBy`:

```kotlin
data.groupBy { it.id }.values.map { it.last() }
```

Another way is `associateBy`, it automatically gets the last element for you:

```kotlin
data.associateBy { it.id }.values.toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one way. I couldn't find any way combining grouping and maxBy. So created unique value set. Then loop and filter the main list with id and get max of that filtered list and add to result.

```
val result = arrayListOf<Test>()
    data.map { it.id }.toSet().forEach {id->
        data.filter {
            it.id == id
        }.maxBy {
            it.timeStamp
        }?.let {
            result.add(it)
        }
    }
```